# How to programmatically change the tab and its content in Jquery without changing tab order?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 5 tabs in my application.I have done it using Jquery. Currently when the page loads it goes to first tab and views its contents. Here i want to load the last tab and its content when the page loads. I don't want to change the tab order. When the page loads it should load the last tab and its contents.I have tried with some code but it loads the first tab and its contents. I have included the html and Jquery code in the following

```
<div class="track-content track-content1" id="tab-container">
                <ul class="track-nav track-nav1" id="ultabs">
                    <li id="liHome"><a href="home.html?oJjeW0EE268roaAJQapM65hyD134lhhhN3F5j7KVQKs=" class="active tabbify" data-id="Home">home</a></li>
                    <li id="linkdailyReport"><a href="Report/DailyReport.html?oJjeW0EE268roaAJQapM65hyD134lhhhN3F5j7KVQKs=" class="tabbify" data-id="dailyReport">Daily Report</a></li>
                    <li id="liTeamReport"><a href="Report/TeamReport.html?oJjeW0EE268roaAJQapM65hyD134lhhhN3F5j7KVQKs=" class="tabbify" data-id="teamReport">Team Report</a></li>
                    <li id="liPulledReport"><a href="Report/PulledReport.html?oJjeW0EE268roaAJQapM65hyD134lhhhN3F5j7KVQKs=" class="tabbify" data-id="PulledReport">Pulled Report</a></li>
                    <li id="liMarkReport"><a href="Report/MarkReport.html?oJjeW0EE268roaAJQapM65hyD134lhhhN3F5j7KVQKs=" class="tabbify" data-id="MarkReport">Marked Report</a></li>

                    <li id="liManagePulled"><a href="Report/ManagePulled.html?oJjeW0EE268roaAJQapM65hyD134lhhhN3F5j7KVQKs=" data-id="ImageUpload" class="tabbify">Image Upload</a></li>
                    <li id="liMetrics"><a href="Metrics/Metric.html?oJjeW0EE268roaAJQapM65hyD134lhhhN3F5j7KVQKs=" data-id="Metric" class="tabbify">Metric</a></li>
                    <li id="liAdmin"><a href="Admin/MaintenanceScreens.html?oJjeW0EE268roaAJQapM65hyD134lhhhN3F5j7KVQKs=" class="tabbify">Admin</a></li>

                    <li id="liLogout" style="float: right; cursor: pointer; padding: 3px 10px;">
                        <img class='homeicon' src="images/Logout.png" alt="Logout" id="Img2" style="width: 24px; height: 24px;" /></li>
                    <li id="lisitedetails" style="float: right; cursor: pointer; padding-top: 3px;">
                        <img class='homeicon' src="images/Facility.png" alt="Facility" id="Img1" style="width: 24px; height: 24px;" /></li>

                    <li style="float: left; cursor: pointer; padding-top: 3px;">
                        <img src="images/Expand.png" id="btnHead" alt="Show/Hide" style="width: 24px; height: 24px;" class='homeicon' />
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- <div style="float: right; position: fixed; display: inline-block; color: white; z-index: 9999999; padding-top: 5px; padding-right: 15px;">
                    <img src="images/Expand.png" id="btnHead" style="width:24px;height:24px;" />
                </div>-->              

                <div id="tabContent" class="tab-content">
                    <!-- Tab Contents Loaded From Ajax -->
                </div>
                <!--#tab-content-->
            </div>
```

$("ul.track-nav").tabs(

```
    "#tabContent",
    {   
        effect: 'ajax', history: true, tabs: 'a.tabbify' ,
    }

  );
```

Comment: can you please pass the parameter in url so that it will move the respective content and tab

Comment: Is it Bootstrap tabs implementation?

Comment: i have included the jquery code in the following..but it is not working. any help is appreciated.$("ul.track-nav").tabs(        
       
        "#tabContent",
        {   
            effect: 'ajax', history: true, tabs: 'a.tabbify' ,
        }
        
      );

Comment: It is not Boostrap tabs implementation

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the tab you want to open by default using the active keyword.

**For example**

If the intended tab to be loaded is the fifth, you may specify it as follows

```
$(function() 
{
      $("#tabs" ).tabs( { active: window.location.hash - 1 } );      
      //subtract one as the tabs are identified based on zero
});
```

This function can be called as soon as your page loads